# WARNING in Circular dependency detected:

Tags: angular

test2\test2.services.ts

```
import { test1Component } from '../test1/test1.component';
constructor(public tsoComp: test1Component ) { }
betState
```

test1.component.ts

```
import { test2Service } from '../test2/test2.services';
constructor(public test2S: test2Service)
someCode(){
  this.test2S.betState = n;
}
```

error:
WARNING in Circular dependency detected:

src\app\layout\sports\sport\test2\test2.services.ts -> src\app\layout\sports\sport\test1\test1.component.ts -> src\app\layout\sports\sport\test2\test2.services.ts

Why is this wrong??

Comment: If you use a component inside your service, you are probably doing something not in the right way. Mixing up dependencies and coupling classes. What's the reason you inject the `Component`?

Answer (score 3):

When angular will look at your code and try to create Objects for your component and the service, it will do that one by one, lets say it starts with creating the service object first, in the service's constructor, you have mentioned that it need a dependency injection of `test1Component` component, then it will say okay lets create an Object of `test1Component`. Now it goes to create an instance of of `test1Component` but there you say that it needs `test2Service` so creation of these instances are deadlocked, so the circular dependency.

Usually we don't inject a component in a service, please check your requirements.